# JAX-WS Handling nested SOAP elements

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, wsimport

Hello Stack community,

I have recently spotted issue with mapping SOAP message to Java objects. I want to automate SOAP tests, where problematic part of message body looks like:

```
<jobData>

 <entryList>
     <name>Key#1</name>
     <entryList>
       <value>Key#1ChildValue</value>
       <name>Key#1ChildKey</name>
     </entryList>
 </entryList>

 <entryList>
   <name>Key#2</name>
   <entryList>
    <value>Key#2ChildValue</value>
    <name>Key#2ChildKey</name>
   </entryList>
 </entryList>
  .
  . // POSSIBLE MORE <entryList> elements
  . 
</jobData>
```

I have used wsimport tool (JDK 8) to parse WSDL. Here is what I got:

**jobData element**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "DataDto", propOrder = {
    "recordedEntries"
})
public class DataDto
    extends DataRowDto
{

    protected RecordedEntriesDto recordedEntries;
    // getter and setter
}
```

**RecordedEntriesDto**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "RecordedEntriesDto", propOrder = {
    "entries"
})
public class RecordedEntriesDto
    extends AbstractVersionableDto
{

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<RecordedEntryDto> entries;
}
```

**RecordetEntryDto**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "RecordedEntryDto", propOrder = {
    "key",
    "value"
})
public class RecordedEntryDto
    extends AbstractVersionableDto
{

    protected String key;
    protected Object value;
```

As it appears, entryList element may contain itself as value.
I have no idea how to nest one in other, because no matter what I try, I always get following error when sending a request:

```
field not serializable: private java.lang.Object com.whateverpackage.RecordedEntryDto.value
```

Now... after few days of searching stack, google, people in company, I gave up, I feel like standing next to enormous brick wall.
I have no impact on SOAP request structure, I can only work on Java code handling it.
Do you have any idea how to deal with it?

Best regards,

Java Auto Tester Newbie

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to have multiple entries?
From your error, i think you are trying to add multiple RecordedEntryDto but you need to use the RecordedEntriesDto Class for that.

---

- Lets say you have 2 entries

```java
RecordedEntryDto entry1 = new RecordedEntryDto();
RecordedEntryDto entry2 = new RecordedEntryDto();
```

- Now you want to have them together in a list

```java
List<RecordedEntryDto> allEntriesList = new ArrayList<>();
allEntriesList.add(entry1);
allEntriesList.add(entry2);
```

- Now you put the list in a RecordedEntr**ies**Dto object

```java
RecordedEntriesDto entriesDto = new RecordedEntriesDto();
entriesDto.setEntries(allEntriesList);
```

- Then you can finish up with the DataDto

```java
DataDto dataDto = new DataDto();
dataDto.setRecordedEntries(entriesDto);
```

Comment: Hi Gerogios. Thank you for reply. Unfortunately this is not that easy and I have been trying such action. I sill get the same error. 
It seems that I cant set DataEntryDto value as DataEntryDto.

Comment: I don't see a DataEntryDto in your post so i 'm not sure if i help you more like this.

I assume uploading the full wsdl is out of the question? Perhaps a version with just the classes for this example?